# (Android) How to match child ID to parent in one-to-many relationship

Tags: android, android-studio, android-room, android-database

[image]

I'm working on an image-like, `one-to-many` database.

To explain the flow of functions, `WorkoutSetInfo` is added to the list whenever the `Add button` is pressed. (`It is not inserted into DB.`)

Finally, when the `Save button` is pressed, the `Workout` and `WorkoutSetInfo list` are inserted into the `DB`.

I have completed setting up the relationship between `Workout` and `WorkoutSetInfo`, but I don't know how to match the `ID` of each `Workout` with Id(`parendWorkoutId`) of `WorktoutSetInfo`.

(Now, all IDs of `parendWorkoutId` are set to `1`.)

How should I set it up?

---

**Workout**

```
@Entity
data class Workout(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val workoutId: Long,
    val title: String = "",
    var unit: String = "kg",
    val memo: String = "",
)
```

**WorkoutSetInfo**

```
@Entity(
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Workout::class,
            parentColumns = arrayOf("workoutId"),
            childColumns = arrayOf("parentWorkoutId"),
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )
    ]
)
data class WorkoutSetInfo(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Long = 0,
    val set: Int,
    var weight: String = "",
    var reps: String = "",
    val parentWorkoutId: Long = 1 // How do I set this up?
)
```

**WorkoutWithSets**

```
data class WorkoutWithSets(
    @Embedded val workout: Workout,
    @Relation (
        parentColumn = "workoutId" ,
        entityColumn = "parentWorkoutId"
    )
    val sets: List<WorkoutSetInfo>
)
```

**Repository**

```
class WorkoutRepository(private val workoutDao : WorkoutDao, title: String) {
    val workout = Workout(0, title)
    private val setInfoList = ArrayList<WorkoutSetInfo>()
    
    fun add() {
        val item = WorkoutSetInfo(set = setInfoList.size + 1)
        setInfoList.add(item)
    }

    fun delete() {
        if(setInfoList.size != 0)
            setInfoList.removeLast()
        return
    }

    fun save() {
        workoutDao.insertWorkout(workout)
        workoutDao.insertSetInfoList(setInfoList)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `workoutDao` interface/abstract class, have the `insertWorkout` function return a **Long**. This will be the **id of the inserted Workout** or **-1 if the insert was ignored**.

Retrieve/Use this returned value and use it to set the `parentWorkoutId` of each element in **setInfoList** within the **save** function.

- of course if the value is -1 then you should handle this appropriately as the Workout would not have been inserted.

E.G.

if you change **parentWorkoutId** from `val` to `var` then the save function could be something like:-

```
fun save(): Boolean {
    var rv = false /* indicate nothing done as insert was ignored */
    val id = workoutDao.insertWorkout(workout)
    if (id > 0) {
        rv = true
        for (wi in setInfoList) {
            wi.parentWorkoutId = id
        }
        workoutDao.insertSetInfoList(setInfoList)
    }
    return rv
}
```

Comment: thanks. Let me ask you a question.

You told workoutDao's insertWorkout function to return a Long type.

But, as I said, `insertWorkout()` and `insertSetInfoList(list)` are executed at the same time in `save()` of Repository. How do I return the value of `insertWorkout()` and use it in `setInfoList`?

Comment: @ybybyb answer edited to show an untested example.